# validation of old value hidden input - laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

I have a problem
I have this radio input which has 3 value , other field input appear depend on value of radio input
here is radion button

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="form-group">
<label> NATIONALITY: </label>
<label for="nationality1" class="ml-5">
<input type="radio" id="nationality1"name="nationality" value="1"
class="nationality" onclick="clearselect()" @if(old('nationality') ==  1 ) checked="checked" @endif>
 NAT_1</label>

<label for="nationality2"><input type="radio" id="nationality2" name="nationality"value="2"class="nationality" onclick="clearselect()"                                                                    @if(old('nationality') ==  2 ) checked="checked" @endif>                                      NAT_2 </label>
  
    
<label for="nationality3"><input type="radio" id="nationality3" name="nationality" value="3" class="nationality" onclick="clearselect()"                                                                     @if(old('nationality') ==  3 ) checked="checked" @endif>                                                                           NAT_4</label>

@if($errors->has('nationality'))
<div class="error">{{ $errors->first('nationality') }}</div>                          @endif </div> </div>
```

and here is other field that depends on radio value

```
 <div class ="hidd">
     <div class="col-xs-12  nationality4 hidd_class1" id="hidd_class1" >
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="user_nationality">Nationality</label>
     <select id="user_nationality" name="nationality_id" class="form-control ">
     <option value=""></option>
     @foreach($nationalities as $nationality)
     <option @if($nationality->id == old('nationality_id')) selected @endif
     value="{{$nationality->id}}">{{$nationality->name}}
     </option>
     @endforeach
     @if($errors->has('nationality_id'))
     <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('nationality_id') }}</div>
     @endif
     </select>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     
    <div class="col-xs-12  hidd_class2 " id="hidd_class2" >
     <div class="form-group "  id="hidd_class5" >
     <label for="IDnumber">ID TYPE *</label>
     <select id="ID_Type" name="id_type_id" class="form-control ">
     <option value=""></option>
     @foreach($idtypes->where('for_saudi',1) as $type)
     <option  @if($type->id == old('id_type_id')) selected @endif
     value="{{$type->id}}" class="sauditypeid">{{$type->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
     @foreach($idtypes->where('for_saudi',0) as $type)
     <option  @if($type->id == old('id_type_id')) selected @endif
     value="{{$type->id}}" class="nonsaud">{{$type->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
     </select>
     @if($errors->has('id_type_id'))
     <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('id_type_id') }}</div>
     @endif
     </div>
     <div class="form-group hidd_class3" id ="hidd_class3" >
     <label for="IDnumber" class="nationality1"> ID NUMBER *</label>
     <input id="IDnumber1" name="id_number[]" type="number"
     class="form-control "
     placeholder="1234567890" value="{{old('id_number.0')}}" >
     @if($errors->has('id_number.0'))
     <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('id_number.0') }}</div>
     @endif
     </div>
    
    
     <div class="form-group IDisExpire hidd_class4" id="hidd_class4" >
     <label for="IDisExpire"> ID_TYPE *</label>
     <select id="IDisExpire" name="id_statue" class="form-control  ">
     option value =""></option>
     option @if(old('id_statue') == '1' )) selected @endif 
     value="1">avilable</option>
     <option @if(old('id_statue') == '0' )) selected @endif value="0"> 
     expire</option>
      </select>
      @if($errors->has('id_statue'))
      <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('id_statue') }}</div>
      @endif
      </div>
    
      <div class="form-group hidd_class " id="hidd_class" >
       <label for="IDdate"> EXPIRE DATE</label>
       <input type="date" id="IDdate" name="expire_id_date" class="form-control "
       value="{{old('expire_id_date')}}" >
       @if($errors->has('expire_id_date'))
       <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('expire_id_date') }}</div>
       @endif
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
```

and js code

```
<script>
 $(".nationality").on('change' ,function(){
            if($(this).val() == '1'){
                $(this).closest('.row').find(".sauditypeid").show();
                $(this).closest('.row').find(".nonsaud").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class1").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class3").show();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class4").show();

            }else if($(this).val() == '2'){
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class1").show();
                $(this).closest('.row').find(".sauditypeid").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find(".nonsaud").show();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class3").show();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class4").show();


            }else if($(this).val() == '3'){
                $(this).closest('.row').find(".nonsaud").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find(".sauditypeid").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class3").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class4").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class1").hide();
                $(this).closest('.row').find("#hidd_class").hide();


            }
        });
</script>

 $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.nationality').change();});
```

my problem is when I choose value 2 of radio button , and select one value of 'user_nationality', which just appear if I choose value 2  , then if I have any validation message , this select input disappear and need again to select it ,
I need to show this select input"user_nationality" with old value if there is any validation message

excuse me for my  english language , hope you understand me , thank tou very much

Comment: the problem you are mentioning in your last paragraph in not clear, plz try to edit it.

Comment: Please format tour code for human readable (remove spaces)

Comment: @bhucho ok , suppose the input with id ='user_nationality' only appear when the value of radio input equal 2 , so myproblem is when I select some element of user_nationality and having any validation error message of any other input so after this happened the input which id ='user_nationality' disappear and again need to select value 2 of radio input and again select user_nationality

Comment: @sta I'm sorry , I will do